# Using Where method with ForEach Loop

Tags: powershell

Just curious if it is possible to use the Where Method in combination with the ForEach loop?

```
$numbers = @(1..10)

ForEach($number in $numbers.Where({$number = 2})){

    Write-Host "the number is $number"

}
```

Ok figured it out

Turns out you can also perform this with Get-ChildItem using the following

```
$start = Get-Date
$end = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$sourcePath = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\"

ForEach($file in ($sourcePath.where({$_.CreationTime -ge $end -and 
$_.CreationTime -le $start}))){

    Write-Host $file.Name

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: -eq not =, $_ not $number `$numbers = 1..10; ForEach($number in $numbers.Where{$_ -eq 2})`

Comment: Is there any reason not to use pipes? `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge $end -and $_.CreationTime -le $start } | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Name }`

Comment: You can get slightly better performance by avoiding the pipeline. Probably immaterial in this case.

Comment: @Dabombber the reason that I can’t use the pipe is because the actual code that this goes in is in a nested loop where I need to use BREAK to get out of that inner loop. However, when using break with pipes, apparently it stops the entire pipe which is why I have to use ForEach so that the outer loop will continue. I was just providing a super super basic example so I could grasp the syntax for the concept to apply to my actual code.

Comment: @N.Ha Yea, that's an annoying way to get caught out. It may make your code more readable if you combine the `Where-Object` with `Get-ChildItem` rather than put it in the loop. `$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -ge $end -and $_.CreationTime -le $start}` and `foreach ($file in $fileList) {`. Or go the other way and use plain `if`s: `foreach ($file in $sourcePath) { if ($file.CreationTime -ge $end -and $file.CreationTime -le $start) { Write-Host $file.Name } }`. Just use whichever seems more appropriate.

Comment: Ooo yeah actually I’ll have to try that since my initial testing didn’t give me the results I had anticipated 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, you do get a nasty level of nesting compared with doing it on the same line as $numbers though.

```
$numbers = @(1..10)

ForEach($number in ($numbers.Where({$_ -eq 2}))){

    Write-Host "the number is $number"

}
```

Comment: so follow up question. Will the Where method work if trying to use it with the Get-ChildItem? For instance

    `$path = "C:\"

    ForEach($file in $path.Where($_.CreationTime -ge $end -and $_.CreationTime -le $start){
       Write-Host "something"
    }`

Comment: Yes you can use the .Where method on the results of Get-Childitem, or any other array. It makes no sense to use it on a string like "C:\" in your example.

Comment: Kind of a weird situation I was in but I was able to figure out the syntax. Thank you so much! Edited original question :D